# How to use directly function key (F1 - F9) instead of pressing fn + function key in IDE in OSX?

Tags: eclipse, macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

When I use shortcuts in any IDE (IntelliJ or Eclipse) in Mac OSX, I have to press <kbd>fn</kbd> + function key (<kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd>). Is there a way avoid it so that I only have to press the function key (<kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd>)? Meanwhile, when I'm not in IDE, I want to use my function keys as app control as usual.

Comment: You haven't asked a question. If you want to provide information on how to do something you must still ask a question and then write your own answer.

Comment: Right. I'll provide a question and answer the question then. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the new MacBook Pro touchbar, we can use simply the function key <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd> in IntelliJ or Eclipse, without having to press <kbd>fn</kbd> + (<kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd>).

We can add IntelliJ or Eclipse in the following configuration:
[image: System Preferences - Keyboard]

After adding IntelliJ or Eclipse in the configuration:
[image]

With that configured, we can now press simply <kbd>F8</kbd> to do *step over* when in debugger in IntelliJ, instead of pressing <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Ventura 13.2.1...

System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts (button) > Function Keys > enable the option below. This option applies if you only want to use <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>function key</kbd> for the functions on the keyboard which is fine by me!

[image]